# How to paginate an API while using Paged List Adapter

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, pagedlist, android-jetpack

I have an application that as a lot of data coming in the web service response. I am using PagedListAdapter but that only mades the pagination in the Room database I think. My question is, is there a way to do pagination to the API using this PagedListAdapter? 
Note: I have a class diff util that I pass to the adapter and I am using Retrofit using the `@Query("page") and @Query("per_page")` in the endpoint

```
class PostDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ProductPost>() {

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: ProductPost?, newItem: ProductPost?) = oldItem?.productId == newItem?.productId

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: ProductPost?, newItem: ProductPost?) = oldItem?.equals(newItem) ?: false

}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: change page-number dynamically and call api again .

Comment: `PagedListAdapter but that only mades the pagination in the Room database I think.` wrong (or at least not necessarily true - depends on the type of data source you use)

Comment: `My question is, is there a way to do pagination to the API using this PagedListAdapter?` not with the paged list adapter directly, but if you have a `DataSource.Factory` wrapped in a `LivePagedListBuilder` then you can set a `BoundaryCallback` which can run the next fetch and write the data to Room

Comment: Can you show an example please? @EpicPandaForce